# axios get request in react-native not working

Tags: axios, react-native

I have integrated axios within my react native application using redux. After setting up axios config I was unable to hit my backend api. Finally I'm hitting a dummy api in component did mount which is also not working.

After wasting 2 days using react native redux and axios, I tried dummy api which is giving response using postman but using axios my api doesn't get called.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';

class IdeaList extends Component {
    componentDidMount = () => {
        debugger;
        let response = axios.get('https://192.168.0.1:63418/Values/Get').then(res => console.log('here comes data',res.data)).catch(err => console.log('err is', err));
        return response
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>IdeaList</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

export default IdeaList;
```

I just want to hit my backend api and get response

Comment: What is the `axios` version are you using?

Comment: "axios": {
      "version": "0.19.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/axios/-/axios-0.19.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-1uvKqKQta3KBxIz14F2v06AEHZ/dIoeKfbTRkK1E5oqjDnuEerLmYTgJB5AiQZHJcljpg1TuRzdjDR06qNk0DQ==",
      "requires": {
        "follow-redirects": "1.5.10",
        "is-buffer": "^2.0.2"
      },

Comment: I notice in your code snippet, you tried to call `httpa://192.168.0.1:63418/Values/Get` which is an invalid address. Can you try a validate url?

Comment: And also, you have a `debugger` code that will pause your program from executing. Try removing it

Comment: I've already tried with http and https , debugger is for checking the response

Comment: You are pausing the `axios` code from executing. Remove the debugger flag.

Comment: LOL.... dude this is for debugging the code, not for pausing the code

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with the way you are making the request and you should see console logs. [Here is a working example](https://snack.expo.io/@remeus/axios-basic-request).

If not then that means there is a problem with you API URL and you should look into it.

However you should note that the `response` variable you have defined will not contain the returned data unless you make the `componentDidMount` an async function and use the [await operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await). In addition, `componentDidMount` does not need to return any value. If you want to use the response in your render function then you should most likely store it in your component's state.

Comment: Atleast my api should get hit where I've used debugger. Instead of using async and await I've used then to deal with the promise

Comment: It's OK to use `then` but by writing `let response = axios.get(...).then(...)` you show that you don't understand what is happening. `reponse` is useless here and will NEVER contains any data returned by the API.

Comment: Since the code is working with a different URL, the problem must come from the API. What is happening on your API side? Do you have any error? Are you sure you are having data returned? Try to log the requests on the server as well as the data right before being returned. We cannot really help you here since we do not have the code of your API.

Comment: I'm also stuck in the same issue but there is no progress. What happens is that when I use some fake api or rest api(hosted api's with some domain name) I get response both using fetch and axios.But when I try hitting my backend api I always get network error. I've tried 10.0.0.2: 59454/api/list, 10.0.2.2: 59454/api/list on genymotion <ipaddress>: 59454/api/list but nothing works